# Fedora not detecting my Hard Drive when installing (Fedora 27)

Tags: fedora, system-installation

I am trying to install Fedora as my primary OS (Completely get rid of Windows), here are the steps I have done:

1. Put the ISO on to my 128GB USB.
2. Booted into the USB and clicked `Install to Hard Drive`
3. I am now on the `Installation Destination` Page]

   - The image is what I currently see.
   - I am expecting my Hard Drive to be an option here, but it's not. Why is this?
     [image: Image of what I see]

   I am using a Dell XPS 13 9350. i5-6200U@2.30GHz, 8GB RAM, 250GB SSD. The USB I'm installing from is 128GB (It worked fine installing to my PC).

## Answer

I finally figured it out. I needed to change my `SATA Operation` in the BIOS from RAID On to AHCI.

Comment: Sometimes Linux can't see drives due to BIOS settings, particularly if you're using something like a motherboard-mounted NVMe drive.

Comment: Are you using EFI or BIOS?

Comment: Can you give more details about your hardware?

Comment: After changing the operation to AHCI, it started listing in linux installation but when I quit and tried to login to windows its getting error message boot disk not found