# Fedora not detecting my new SSD device on install to hard drive program

Tags: fedora, upgrade, ssd

I bought an older Thinkpad W500 which has windows 7 and a HD with the intention of installing Fedora/linux.  I have done this before on another windows laptop.

This time...i purchases a new crucial SSD.  I took out the old HD, put in the new SSD.  The computer boots fine to the Fedora Live CD...but when I go to install to hardrive, there is no way to select the SSD drive...it says no hard drive detected.

I saw a similar post here where the solution was to go to the bios and change the SATA setting to AHCI or something...but mine is already set to that.

I am wondering...since its a new SSD...do I need to initialize it or something...not sure what the issue is..thanks.

previous post
[Fedora not detecting my Hard Drive when installing (Fedora 27)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/414889/fedora-not-detecting-my-hard-drive-when-installing-fedora-27)

Comment: SSD is probably the red herring here. If you put the old spinning HDD back in, does Live OS detect it and allow you to partition? It sounds more like you have an issue with SATA controller than with a drive attached to it. Can you post the output of `lspci` from live terminal?

Comment: Do you see it in the bios?