# fedora installation, drive not found

Tags: fedora, ssd, bios

[image]im trying to install fedora workstation alongside windows 10 on my laptop (never did this before). Im using a live-usb to install it. I can boot into the usb just fine using the boot menu from windows.
When im in the live version and try to install it, the list of locations where I can install it to is just empty, and fedora does not seem to see any drives.
My laptop has only one drive, an SSD where windows is installed on and that I partitioned for this new installation. I rly have no idea whats going on.

I included a picture of my bios boot order, there are just 2 devices, my SSD and the live-usb, I dont see if there is something wrong.

thx for thte help[image]

Comment: From the Live environment, open a terminal and type `sudo fdisk -l` and post the results here.

Comment: @ajgringo619 yes thank you, I added the results of this above.

Comment: When it comes to the partition where you are trying to install Fedora, did you partition it in Windows with an NTFS filesystem?

Comment: This could be a problem with the BIOS either being in IDE/RAID mode instead of AHCI. I found these links that I believe pertain to your issue: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/414889/fedora-not-detecting-my-hard-drive-when-installing-fedora-27 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/696413/ubuntu-installer-cant-find-any-disk-on-dell-xps-13-9350

Comment: The text "SAMSUNG MZVLW256HEHP-000L2" indicates the SSD is Samsung PM961. That is a NVMe device, so the IDE/RAID vs. AHCI distinction does not apply. Linux names NVMe devices like `/dev/nvme0n1` and their partitions as `/dev/nvme0n1pN` where N is a number. (`n1` is a namespace ID; generally consumer NVMe storage devices have just one namespace, while enterprise devices could have more.)