# Installation can't detect hard drive(SSD) in Fedora(anaconda)&Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, centos, fedora, software-installation, hard-disk

Context:  I have always had trouble installing Linux in my ACER SPIN5 SP513 Series. For  installation I have to "Select an UEFI as trusted for executing", then EFI, then BOOT and then 'shimx64.efi' and place it a the top in the the Bios and in that way I installed some distros, ultimately Ubuntu because I have noticed that my pc was turning slower. In the image, "Linux" (not the best name) was the select UEFI that I had before, it was Ubuntu and I don't why it is there, I have reset the settings a couple of times.

[image: usual order for booting and it worked pretty well]

I wanted to install a lighter distro but when I tried with Lubuntu and Lite, I couldn't even enter to the installer, because after doing the process I mentioned, I couldn't see them via F12. After a couple of times, I decided to try Fedora but this time with Anaconda Installer, I couldn't see my SSD, just the bootable device (the USB).I tried with Ubuntu20 and displaying that I only had 4 Gb of space (the USB).

I have seen a couple of similar posts but I don't actually know what to do. [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/414889/fedora-not-detecting-my-hard-drive-when-installing-fedora-27) was possibly the most concise solution but I don't know how to change my SATA OPERATION, also, in the BIOS 'Information' appears:

```
HDD Model Name:         None
HDD Serial Number:      None
SATA Mode:              AHCI
```

So... that solution might not work. Also I tried:

```
sudo dmraid -r -E /dev/sda
no block devices found
```

This is the actual state of my disk:

```
sudo fdisk -lu /dev/sda
```

[image: Can't see my SSD!]

In conclusion, I'm quite lost and my questions are:

1. What could be a cause of the "disappearance" of my SSD?
2. Why can't I see it?
3. What is dmraid and what can i do with it?
4. What is AHCI and RAID? and what are the differences among them?
5. Most important, how can I fix this, installing a distro and leaving my pc as it was before with Ubuntu 19.10 or any other distro?
   Extra:
6. Do you have any idea if there is anyway of updating my BIOS in order to make more efficient the installation process of GNU/Linux distros?

Sorry for the long post and lots of question but there are many concepts that can be explained, that beginners as me might not understand. I hope you can help me and thanks in advance!

[Plz, if I need to edit something in my post, I would gladly do it! Just starting in this community and feedback is relevant to me]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. How old is the SSD? Did you physically adjust or reseat it recently or anything of the sort? You say your PC was running slower... how long have you noticed this?

   Unfortunately, based on what you have said, it sounds like your SSD might have died. SSDs have "write endurance" ratings; you can only write so much data to them before they give up the ghost. When they do, they don't show up at all in the UEFI or BIOS, even when plugged in. The slowness you mentioned having noticed is sometimes indicative of the SSD's write endurance threshold being approached and the built-in controller trying to find flash memory that can still be written to. It's also indicative of SSD drives that are mostly full; most SSD drives' performance nosedives when it's mostly full.
2. See #1.
3. dmraid - Device Mapper RAID. Basically lets you configure, setup, and use software RAID.
4. AHCI stands for Advanced Host Controller Interface and effectively is "Standard" mode for regular SSDs / hard drives. RAID stands for Redundant Array of Independent Disks and is routinely used in enterprise environments, servers, etc. It sounds a bit outside of the scope of what you need right now, but feel free to [read about RAID levels via this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels)
5. If the drive is dead, the only recourse is to buy a new drive, I'm afraid. Maybe the drive is not properly connected via something you did not describe and it can be reseated.
6. Check the manufacturer's website, look up the specific make and model number, and there potentially are BIOS updates available. Sometimes some interesting bug fixes are there, sometimes new features are added, but it's a roll of the dice what you will find. My logic is always "These computer companies have some very smart and talented people making these BIOS updates, I think it's a good idea to apply them to keep the computer systems under my control up-to-date."

Comment: Hey Deputy! thanks for the quick response. I bought my computer in November 2016, I didn't do anything particular with my SSD, it was functioning normal. For the last couple weeks, the first case was when I tried to fetch a book (quite long) and it freezed, so forced shutdown. Well... If that's the case, is there any way from checking further the disk status? From terminal I mean. Thanks for the info, very useful.

Comment: Well... I also remembered another thing, I didn't think it was relevant but I would like to know your opinion. I had set 2 passwords, one for accessing the BIOS and other for unlocking the SSD. When my boot process failed first, the password from the SDD disappeared, I didn't remove remove it, just went ghost. Does that give you more suspects that my SSD is dead?

Answer (score 0):

Try going to BIOS/UEFI then look for the device setting AHCI/RAID and double check that it is set to AHCI. If it is set to RAID, then change it and don't forget to save. I ran into this not long ago, where some laptop manufacturers set this by default to RAID, which then stops the drive completely from being seen within any linux that I tried.